# How do I talk to my boss about transferring to another office/promotion?

Tags: management, career-development, promotion

I have been working in my current role for over 2 years now. I had started off as an office assistant and was promoted to manager within a year. My boss keeps saying how happy he is with my work, and had originally planned to promote me to a bigger office as manager, which I was looking forward to. But, due to various changes within my current office, my boss changed his plans, and had someone else take over as manager at the bigger office. Soon after, he had a talk with me about how due to the growth happening at my office, he needs me here, and the bigger office is off the table. That was a month ago, and back then I told him I understand, and still expressed interest to eventually move to another bigger office.

Things have settled down now, and my current office is under control. How and when should I bring about my interest to move to a bigger office/role with my boss? Would appreciate your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How and when should I bring about my interest to move to a bigger
>   office/role with my boss? Would appreciate your advice.

Just talk about it with your boss. Do it now.

Something like "I know we talked about this in the past, and at that time you said that you needed me here. It seems like things are now settled down, so I'd like to talk about how I can get promoted and moved to a bigger office." should work.

In addition, some companies have a formally defined process for internal moves. Find out if that's the case in your company and follow the process for whatever is required. In most cases, you'll need to inform your current manager.